# grep not behaving with 0 in expression

Tags: linux, grep, centos

Im sure there is perfectly simple explanation to my issue here but it has confused me.

I am using centos standard grep searching a file for the following string :

```
0.000 kB / 0.0 sec
```

I am pretty sure I have done this a million times before and never had a problem, but right now I get this :

```
grep "0.000 kB / 0.00 sec" flash.log

672.881 kB / 0.95 sec
```

It is not the "/" which is the problem as I have also tried this :

```
grep "000" flash.log

672.881 kB / 0.95 sec
```

As I understood a 0 is not a special character in any way even though it seems to be reacting as one here?

I know I can fix the issue using this :

```
grep -e "0.000 kB / 0.00 sec" flash.log
```

But just dont understand what the difference is by using the -e for pattern or what the significance of the 0 is or how grep is interpreting it?

Comment: Looks like it is interpreting it as a formatting character: "find numbers like this".

Comment: The grep works for me. Are you sure flash.log contains what you are searching for? I've tested on Centos 6.3

Comment: i am looking for : 0.000 kB / 0.00 sec

Comment: so why does it return : 672.881 kB / 0.95 sec << is completely different as i am looking for a literal string

Comment: @user1828008 Yes I know. but are you sure the file contains that pattern?

Comment: I've tested again the grep is working for me. It will only output the lines with '0.000 kB / 0.00 sec' not other ones that contain '672.881 kB / 0.95 sec' or anything else

Comment: no the file does NOT contain the pattern so i want it to return nothing and an exit code of 1 which is what i would have expected it to do, but instead it is returning a line which it shouldnt and an exit code of 0

Comment: `echo "672.881 kB / 0.95 sec" | grep "0.000 kB / 0.0 sec"` prints nothing - are you *sure* you're running the expression you think you are against the file you think you are? (In general you ought to be escaping the `.` though, but this isn't related to what you're observing here)

Comment: I'm with Flexo. I got no output and return code 1. As expected. On CentOS 6.3

Comment: your grep was slightly diff but i agree yes if i do :

echo "672.881 kB / 0.95 sec" | grep "0.000 kB / 0.00 sec" 

it shows nothing. my original grep command and output is a cut and paste from the terminal so yeah im certain its running what i want, and i can do it with a -e and it does not return the line which is what it should do.

But whats the difference with or without the -e for a pure text string?

Comment: its not a pure text string.. mind the '.'

Comment: yes i did think about escaping the . in there but then tried just grep "000" flash.log and it shows the record

Comment: can you post flash.log to pastebin?

Comment: Problem solved thanks to perleone and his answer below. Thanks all for your help !!! Damn ^M ......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your originally matched line probably has a `^M` as line ending. Pipe your grep output through `cat -A` or `less` or `hd` to actually see what you're getting, and not let your terminal interpret it. Because `^M` means carriage return (and *not* line feed, thank you Carl), so the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line and overwrites the actual match. Here's my example flash.log which behaves just like you described:

```
0.000 kB / 0.00 sec^M672.881 kB / 0.95 sec
```

Look at it with `vi -b` or `cat -A`.

Comment: ^M means carriage return, which explains the behaviour.  A line feed would work as expected for the OP.

Comment: Thank you, I always get the explanation for those two mixed up.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you !!!! Yes that was it, your absolutely right I can see it now. So am I interpreting this right.. the reason why with -e it doesnt show is once again because of the ^M which means it is simply not showing it on the screen?

Comment: @user1828008, it's probably showing it on the screen, it's just immediately overwriting it with the next line's data.  Unless you had pretty fast eyes, you wouldn't see it.

Comment: ignore me, it does show it i had the wrong string in my grep -e which is why it didnt show me... oops.... thanks !!!

Comment: do i have to do anything to mark the question as closed? im fairly new on here? maybe if an admin can do so it would be appreciated